# Encode to X12 by agreement name unauthorized

Tags: azure, integration, azure-logic-apps, x12

I have a simple logic app that picks up an XML file and translates it into X12.  I am able to select schema and maps from the integration account in the designer with no problem.  But when I add an "Encode to X12 by Agreement Name" step, I can't select the agreement name in the drop down box.  There is an error message displayed that says "Could not retrieve values. error executing the api /listagreements". I tried to type the name manually, but then the app run fails on the X12 encode step with the text "Unauthorized" in the graphical runs history.  A closer look at the error outputs shows this:

```
"body": {
    "StatusCode": "Unauthorized",
    "ErrorMessage": "Integration account operation failed with status code: Unauthorized and error AuthorizationFailed : The authentication credentials are not valid.",
    "source": "x12-eus.azconn-eus.p.azurewebsites.net"
```

There is no mention of requiring credentials anywhere.  The subscription is the free level and I have two trading partners, two schema, one map and one agreement.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the Agreement you made set to the correct type (X12)? You can choose out of 3 types (AS2, X12, EDIFACT) and default is AS2.

Comment: I was able to fix this by deleting the old connection and creating a new one.  I believe you are correct about the connection type being incorrect.

Comment: Fixed.  Wrong connection type. But now I am having a different problem.  The output is base64 encoded.  When I try to apply the following conversion to the output, changing the code from 

"@body('Encode_to_X12_message_by_agreement_name')?['Payload']"
to 
"@base64ToString(body('Encode_to_EDIFACT_message_by_agreement_name')?['Payload'])"

, I get this error when I try to save:

Failed to save logic app TestApp. The template validation failed: 'The action(s) 'Encode_to_EDIFACT_message_by_agreement_name' referenced by 'inputs' in action 'Create_blob' are not defined in the template.'.